# Giving a string that changes a string variable

Tags: python, variables, exec

I have a list of names I would like to pass to some variables, however the variables have each a unique name. I'm iterating through because in this example the variables seem few but in my real scenario the would be to much to write out and assign a list value.

```
names = ["apple", 1, 50, "boat", 5, 90, "tree", 4, 96]

n1=q1=t1=""
n2=q2=t2=""
n3=q3=t3=""

name = 0
quantity = 1
total = 2

value = len(names)
value = (value // 3) + 1

for i in range(1, value):
    tempN = "n" + str(i)
    tempQ = "q" + str(i)
    tempT = "t" + str(i)

    # using locals(), when i print the variables, n1, q1, t1...they all end up empty .
    # using exec() I get this error, all the examples to solve this error wasn't very helpful 
    # since most of them had to do with input from the user.
    #    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    #    NameError: name 'apple' is not defined

    locals()[tempN] = names[name]
    locals()[tempQ] = names[quantity]
    locals()[tempT] = names[total]
    exec("%s = %s" % (tempN, names[name]))
    exec("%s = %s" % (tempQ, names[quantity]))
    exec("%s = %s" % (tempT, names[total]))

    name += 3
    quantity += 3
    total += 3
```

This is somewhat a very big oversimplification but the idea remains the same, I have many variables that need to get a value from the list. everything can be changed but the lists format, or the fact that it is a list.

Does anyone know a better way to do this or have a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of Python's data structures, especially [`dictionaries`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which will usually result in less code written and makes your code more readable than using `eval` function.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(dict)
keys = ['name', 'quantity', 'total']
names = ["apple", 1, 50, "boat", 5, 90, "tree", 4, 96]

for i, values in enumerate(
    [names[x:x + len(keys)] for x in range(0, len(names), len(keys))]
):
    result[i] = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(result)
```

Out:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
            {0: {'name': 'apple', 'quantity': 1, 'total': 50},
             1: {'name': 'boat', 'quantity': 5, 'total': 90},
             2: {'name': 'tree', 'quantity': 4, 'total': 96}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just splitting the list into sublists could help you

```
list = ["apple", 1, 50, "boat", 5, 90, "tree", 4, 96]
sublists = [list[x:x+3] for x in range(0,len(list),3)]
for element in sublists:
   print(element)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['apple', 1, 50]
['boat', 5, 90]
['tree', 4, 96]
```